# ConfigurationErrorException when debugging on Visual Studio 2010, .Net Framework 4, 32-bit

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, 32-bit, visual-studio-debugging

I've run across an issue when debugging applications on VS 2010.

This is a simple command-line app:

```
namespace HttpTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public void testHTTP ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating HTTP request. Press a key to proceed.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com");
            Console.WriteLine("Getting response...");
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program app = new Program();
            app.testHTTP();
        }
   }
}
```

If I launch/debug it from Visual Studio 2010, I get a **ConfigurationErrorsException** when creating the HttpWebRequest:

> Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section.

This is quite suprising, as my app.config has no entry in system.net/defaultProxy (and neither does my devenv.exe.config).

By trying different settings, I found out that *the error only happens if I set the target framework to 4.0 and the target platform to x86 and try to debug within VS*

- If I build it and run it from the command line (regardless of build settings), I have no issues.
- If I set the target Framework to 3.5, the error disappears and the app debugs normally.
- If I set the platform target to 'x64' or 'Any CPU', the app debugs normally.
- If I build on 4.0/x86, run from command line, attach the debugger while waiting for the first key press, then proceed, I get the error mentioned above.
- I have disabled the firewall on my machine
- Running VS as administrator makes no difference to the test.
- If I try this on a different machine, same hardware specs and OS, belonging to a colleague, I can debug it within VS2010.

It obviously has something to do with the settings on my machine. However, I have been unable to isolate what the conditions are.

Other users suggested moving the application to the C: drive. I don't think this applies to my case, as I can run int successfully from the D: drive. Issue happens only when debugging within VS.

Comment: You should look at `%windir%/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Config/web.config` (4.0/x86) which contains system.net machine-wide settings.

Comment: Right, I checked there and what I have is this:    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy>
            <proxy usesystemdefault="true" />
        </defaultProxy>      I don't have any proxies defined in my system (checked in IE settings and in group policy editor).
    </system.net>